# Can't run Windows Update: error 0x800f081f

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My system has been stuck in this for ~2 months.  Windows Update states I've missing security and quality fixes with the following message:

```
There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this 
and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help: (0x800f081f)
```

After a lot of Googling, I've tried a few things to fix it with no luck:

### sfc

```
sfc /scannow
```

this always returns:

```
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

### DISM.exe

I run:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

which always returns:

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.329

Image Version: 10.0.19041.388

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

### Manual Install

I've downloaded the update and manually install them, but they always fail.  The dialog simply says "Some updates were not installed" and then lists them.   No other additional information.

### Troubleshooter

I've tried to run the Windows Update Troubleshooter, but it says it "No recommended troubleshooters" right now & I don't see a way to force it?

### .NET Framework is enabled

I've checked that the  .NET Framework is enabled (as instructed [here](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-error-0x800f081f/), step 5)

### Next steps?

Any suggestions on what to try?  I'm a recent convert from the Mac, so a bit of a fish out of water in trying to figure out what's going on.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What reason do the Windows Update logs indicate for the failure of the manual patch failures?  Have you tried manually upgrading to 20H2 with the upgrade assistant?

Comment: Try the advice in [Troubleshoot problems updating Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/troubleshoot-problems-updating-windows-10-188c2b0f-10a7-d72f-65b8-32d177eb136c), "Advanced" section. If none works for you, try the [Microsoft Windows Update Troubleshooter for Windows 10](https://aka.ms/wudiag).

Comment: Sometimes, I've had to resort to downloading the whole Windows ISO, using the Media Creation Tool, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 , and reinstalling Windows (trying to keep existing files). Of course, make and verify a disk image before starting the reinstall!

Comment: Please download [Windows Update Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and have a try. The Update Assistant can help you update to the latest version of Windows 10.

Comment: @Sunny This fixed it.  If you want to add it as an answer, I'll upvote it & mark it as answered, so you receive the karma.

Comment: [DISM and .NET Framework Error 0x800F081F in Windows 10](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/dism-restorehealth-error-0x800f081f-windows-10/)

Comment: @BillReardon glad to hear it's helpful to you and thanks for your confirmation, I have posted it as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download Windows Update Assistant from the following link and have a try. The Update Assistant can help you update to the latest version of Windows 10.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed it!

Comment: This just says thanks for updating to windws 10

Answer (score 1):

Error Code 0x800f081f means CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING.

Perform a in-place upgrade (Repair Installation).

Have you installed a 3rd party Antivirus and/or a Firewall Program?

When yes, go to Step 1. When not, go to Step 2.

Step 1:
Uninstall the antivirus/firewall program use the removal tool of the respective manufacturer of the antivirus or firewall program also.

A list can be found at the link below:

https://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/sln208651/utilities-to-completely-remove-antivirus-software?lang=en

Step 2:
Then perform a Windows Repair Installation.

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html

Friendly greetings

Sorry for any mistakes. English is not my native language.

Answer (score -2):

just download new win10 version & update!
https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_20H2_English_x64.iso?t=709afcd2-4837-4071-a597-eb170b5ac793&e=1609585353&h=3b367a700b7cea442c331daa205c0913
enjoy!